# Calculating the maximum number of an array by divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I made a program that calculates the maximum value of an array using the divide and conquer algorithm, but the output is 0.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int array[50];

void maximum(int index1, int index2, int&max_number) {
    int max_number1;
    int max_number2;
    int half;
    if (index1 == index2)
        max_number = array[index1];
    else {
        half = (index1 + index2) / 2;
        maximum(index1, half, max_number1);
        maximum(half + 1, index2, max_number2);
        if(max_number1 < max_number2)
        max_number = max_number2;
        else
        max_number = max_number1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int index1;
    int index2;
    int max_number = 0;
    cout << "index2 = ";
    cin >> index2;
    for (index1 = 0; index1 < index2; index1++)
        cin >> array[index1];
        maximum(index1, index2, max_number);
    cout << "maximum number = " << max_number;
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: This call maximum(index1, index2, max_number); does not make sense because index1 is equal to index2 after the previous loop.

Comment: Why not just use what the standard library already provides: [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Likely the goal is to understand how to write a divide and conquer algorithm, not calculate a max element of some specific array.

Comment: @Rotem Possibly. But then the question should say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo in this part of code

```
for(index1 = 0; index1 < index2; index1++)
```

index1 will increased till to index2, and then

```
maximum(index1, index2, max_number);
```

will pass the same the same values in the 1st/2nd parameter, you may change the code like as

```
for(index1 = 0; index1 < index2; index1++)
    cin>>array[index1];
index1 = 0;
maximum(index1, index2, max_number);
```

Comment: @ Jesper Juh The function in the question is a recursive function. The standard algorithm is not a recursive function and does not uses the approach "divide and conquer".

Answer (score 1):

After this loop

```
for(index1 = 0; index1 < index2; index1++)
cin>>array[index1];
```

`index1` is equal to `index2`. So this call

```
maximum(index1, index2, max_number);
```

does not make sense.

In any case the function is too complicated and uses global variables that is a bad practice of programming.

The recursive function can be written much simpler using the standard algorithm `std::max`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

size_t maximum( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    return n < 2 ? 
           0     : 
           std::max( maximum( a, n / 2 ), 
                     n / 2 + maximum( a + n / 2, n - n / 2 ), 
                     [a] ( size_t i, size_t j ) { return a[i] < a[j]; } );  
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int b[N] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    int c[N] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 };

    size_t pos = maximum( a, N );
    std::cout << "The maximum element is " << a[pos] 
              << " at position " << pos  << std::endl;

    pos = maximum( b, N );
    std::cout << "The maximum element is " << b[pos] 
              << " at position " << pos  << std::endl;

    pos = maximum( c, N );
    std::cout << "The maximum element is " << c[pos] 
              << " at position " << pos  << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The maximum element is 9 at position 9
The maximum element is 9 at position 0
The maximum element is 9 at position 5
```